# Python Pandas change date column with format YYYYMMDD to MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I have a dataframe with a column 'Valuation Date'. The data for this comes in the format YYYYMMDD. I need to change this to a normal date string (MM-DD-YYYY). This is what I have been using, but it isn't working.

It does not want to cycle through each value (only pulls the first value and uses it for each of the 84k rows. It is also iterating, which I want to avoid. Is there an easier way to do this?

There are 0 values in the data, keeping them 0 is necessary. All others need to be changed to the MM-DD-YYYY format.

```
for val in df['Valuation Date']:
    if val == 0:
        val == 0
    else:
        val = str(val)
        vy = val[:4]
        vm = val[4:6]
        vd = val[6:8]
        val = date(int(vy),int(vm),int(vd))   
        df['Valuation Date'] = val
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**End Solution provided by @thomask**

```
def change_format(val):
    if val == 0:
        val == 0
    else:
        val = str(val)
        date = datetime.strptime(val,"%Y%M%d")
        new_date = date.strftime("%Y-%M-%d")
        return new_date

df['Valuation Date'] = df['Valuation Date'].apply(change_format)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strptime` and `strftime` of `datetime.datetime` methods:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def change_format(val):
    val = str(val)
    date = datetime.strptime(val, "%Y%M%d")
    new_date = date.strftime("%Y-%M-%d")
    return new_date
```

Example :

```py
change_format("20220622")
>>> "2022-06-22"
```

Then, you can apply this function to you dataframe series:

```py
df['Valuation Date'].apply(change_format)
```

Comment: I have zeros in some of the data. This breaks on the zeros. Could add this to the for loop but trying not to iterate. takes way too long.

Comment: You can add this condition on the `change_format` function

Comment: awesome, thank you for the help. Added an if function to account for the zeros.

Comment: @snek watch out, in your edited solution, in your `if` statement, you must write `val = 0` and add an `return val` statement. For now, if `val` equals 0, you are returning `None`.

Answer (score 2):

it helps when you post the data to be able to reproduce. but, this seems to answer what you're looking for

```
df['Valuation Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Valuation Date']).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
```

Comment: not sure why but this doesn't work. All dates stayed in the same YYYYMMDD format

Comment: I have not assigned back the result to d['Valuation'], you need to do that. I update the solution to assigned the value back. try it

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the date in `Pandas dataFrame` using `pd.to_datetime` module. For your solution kindly refer the `Code Snippet` mentioned below: -

```
# Import all the Important Modules
import pandas as pd

# Data Regeneration 
df = pd.DataFrame({'Valuation Date': {0: '20160126', 1: '20160127'}})

# Date Conversion from 'YYYYMMDD' to 'MM-DD-YYYY'
df['Valuation Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Valuation Date']).dt.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

# Print Result
print(df)
```

```
# Output of above Code Snippet
      Valuation Date
0     01-26-2016
1     01-27-2016
```

> To know more about **pd.to_datetime** : - [Click Here !!!](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: this results in reformat of the data but i'm now getting "00-01/01/70-1970" for every value. Not sure why it's doing that.

Comment: As you mentioned, there were '0' in dates and a few values which might give you the wrong `Output`. So, can you provide a few date's data? In which you are getting the wrong results.